# How did ancient people treat acne?

Tags: medicine, disease

In the modern era,  people have creams and antibiotics to treat acne. How did ancient people treat acne given that there is rarely an ancient picture which illustrates ancient people with acne. Did different civilizations (e.g Asia,  Europe,  Greek,  etc.) have different ways of treating acne?

Comment: FWIW there were much more serious skin conditions to worry about -- like [smallpox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smallpox), Syphilis, Polio, Leprosy, etc. (They [did worry about it](https://www.racked.com/2018/4/12/17071814/acne-treatment-history) though.)

Comment: If you simply google 'acne history' you'll get plenty of sources on the 1st page of results, including honey and sulphur as treatments. I would suggest you edit your question to take account of easily available sources or else this question is likely to be closed as too basic.

Comment: Welcome to History:SE. Could you edit your question to clarify what you've looked into already, complete with links and references, and context if applicable? In particular, please let us know what you find missing or unclear about the Wikipedia entry on the topic, if one exists. This allows those who might want to answer to do so without needing to redo the work you've already done. You might find it helpful to review the site tour and Help Centre and, in particular, How to Ask.

Answer (score 3):

Like the comment says this is pretty easy to google but here's something to help you.

From https://www.racked.com/2018/4/12/17071814/acne-treatment-history

> Ancient Egyptians and Greeks used honey in their treatment of acne.
>   Celsus recommended “galbanum and soda pounded in vinegar to the
>   consistency of honey” for removing spots.

From http://www.bestacnetreatment.org/history-of-acne-and-its-treatment/

> In Rome 2000 years ago, bathing in hot sulfur mineral waters was one
>   of the few available acne treatments. Sulfur was a treatment
>   throughout the 19th century, and still is with us.

In ancient China they used acupuncture and to herbs help with acne. The article called [Acupuncture and Facial Rejuvenation](https://academic.oup.com/asj/article/25/4/419/190569) has lots more information.